# CSS Bootstrap put button on right bottom corner

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I need help putting a button in the bottom-right corner of a Bootstrap `col`.
I want to put the button where the black outline is in the image below.

```
<div class="container-fluid m-0">
<div class="d-flex bg-secondary m-0 rounded">     
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm bg-info">
        <div>
        </div>
     </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
       <h3> Username</h3>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque dolor leo, iaculis eu rhoncus quis</p>
       <p>xxx Followers . xxx Following</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm bg-danger">
      <p class="ml-auto">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</button>
      </p>
    </div>
           
        
    </div>
   </div>

</div>
```

[image: Button place]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out--

```
<div class="container-fluid m-0">
<div class="d-flex bg-secondary m-0 rounded">     
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm bg-info">
    <div>
    </div>
 </div>
<div class="col-sm">
   <h3> Username</h3>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque dolor leo, iaculis eu rhoncus quis</p>
   <p>xxx Followers . xxx Following</p>
</div>
<div class="col-sm bg-danger">
  <p style="height: 100%" class="d-flex justify-content-end align-items-end">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</button>
  </p>
</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: What does this do? Please explain your code so that it is more useful for readers.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="bg-secondary rounded">
    <div class="container bg-secondary">
      <div class="row align-items-stretch">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm bg-info"></div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm">
          <div class="py-3">
            <h3> Username</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque dolor leo, iaculis eu rhoncus quis</p>
            <p>xxx Followers . xxx Following</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm bg-danger">
          <div class="h-100 d-flex align-items-end justify-content-end py-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does this do? Please explain your code so that it is more useful for readers.

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods to implement this...

The first method:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="bg-secondary rounded">
    <div class="container bg-secondary">
      <div class="row align-items-stretch">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm bg-info"></div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm">
          <div class="py-3">
            <h3> Username</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque dolor leo, iaculis eu rhoncus quis</p>
            <p>xxx Followers . xxx Following</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm bg-danger">
          <div class="h-100 d-flex align-items-end justify-content-end py-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the easiest one.

The second method:

1. Go to `index.css` or `App.css` or you can go to any other CSS file if you have imported it into your file.

Write this piece of code:

```
.col-sm {
    height: 100%; !important
    display: flex; !important
    justify-content: flex-end; !important
    align-items: flex-end; !important
}
```

You can also give a class and then write the CSS code based on the class.